# How could we implement a garage door keeping track of what was its last moving direction?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, logic, character

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Killer Garage Door](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58b1ae711fcffa34090000ea). The statement is:

> Situation
>
> You have been hired by a company making electric garage doors.
>   Accidents with the present product line have resulted in numerous
>   damaged cars, broken limbs and several killed pets. Your mission is to
>   write a safer version of their controller software. Specification
>
> We always start with a closed door. The remote control has exactly one
>   button, with the following behaviour.
>
> ```
> If the door is closed, a push starts opening the door, and vice-versa
> It takes 5 seconds for the door to open or close completely
> While the door is moving, one push pauses movement, another push resumes movement in the same direction
> ```
>
> In order to make the door safer, it has been equiped with
>   resistance-based obstacle detection. When the door detects an
>   obstacle, it must immediately reverse the direction of movement. Input
>
> A string where each character represents one second, with the
>   following possible values.
>
> ```
> '.' No event
> 'P' Button has been pressed
> 'O' Obstacle has been detected (supersedes P)
> ```
>
> As an example, '..P....' means that nothing happens for two seconds,
>   then the button is pressed, then no further events. Output
>
> A string where each character represents one second and indicates the
>   position of the door (0 if fully closed and 5 fully open). The door
>   starts moving immediately, hence its position changes at the same
>   second as the event. Example
>
> ..P...O..... as input should yield 001234321000 as output

I have written the following code:

```
public class Door {
  public static String run(String events) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\nevents: "+events);
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean movingUp = false;
    boolean movingDown = false;

    for(char c : events.toCharArray()){
      System.out.println("movingUp: "+movingUp);
      System.out.println("movingDown: "+movingDown);
      System.out.println("c: "+c);
      System.out.println("count: "+count);
      System.out.println("result: "+result);
      if(c=='.'){
        if(movingUp){
          result.append(count < 5 ? ++count : 5);
        }else if(movingDown){
          result.append(count > 0 ? --count : 0);
        }else{
          result.append(count);
        }
      }else if(c=='P'){
        if(count==5){
          movingUp = false;
          movingDown = true;
          result.append(count > 0 ? --count : 0);
        }else if(movingUp){
          movingUp = false;
          result.append(count);
        }else if(movingDown){
          movingDown = false;
          result.append(count);
        }else{
          movingUp = true;  
          result.append(count < 5 ? ++count : 5);
        }
      }else if(c=='O'){
        movingUp = false;
        movingDown = true;
        result.append(count > 0 ? --count : 0);
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

I was wondering how could we handle, when there is a pause and then the door resumes again, to be able to keep it going up or down, as it was doing before the pause?

Here are some tests, the ones marked with →, are the ones where the pause or obstacle behaviour fails because of currently the code assumes that after a pause it should go upwards, and after an obstacle it should go downwards.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MainTest {
  @Test
  public void testNormalOperation() {
    test("should stay closed unless button is pressed (no buttonpresses)", "..........", "0000000000");
    test("should start opening on buttonpress", "P..", "123");
    test("should open completely and stay open", "P....", "12345");
  }

  @Test
  public void testPause() {
    test("should start opening and pause on second buttonpress", "P.P..", "12222");
    test("→ should resume closing on third buttonpress", ".....P......P.P..P....", "0000012345554333321000");
  }

  @Test
  public void testObstacles() {
    test("should reverse while opening", "P.O....", "1210000");
    test("→ should reverse while closing", "P.O....", "12345554345555");
  }

  @Test
  public void testObstaclePlusPause () {
    test("→ should reverse while opening (and allow pause)", "P..OP..P..", "1232222100");
  }

  @Test
  public void testExample() {
    test("should start opening and reverse when obstacle", "..P...O.....", "001234321000");
  }

  private void test(String description, String events, String result) {
    assertEquals(description ,result, Door.run(events));
  }
}
```

I have also read:

- https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/lectures/summary_state_pattern.php

How could we implement a garage door keeping track of what was its last moving direction?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  So in the interest of keeping your code intact I attempted
to introduce as few changes as needed.

However one correction is needed before proceeding - one of your test cases
is not correct, the 2nd test case in testObstacles is not valid.

Was:

```
test("→ should reverse while closing", "P.O....", "12345554345555");

// in the above the first 'P' would start it "12" and the first "O" should
// immediately reverse it (which would be reversing while opening) "1000"
```

So assuming the text is correct and the expected result is correct then the input should be:

```
test("→ should reverse while closing", "P.......P.O....", "12345554345555");
```

**Short answer:**

Introduce a boolean which records the previous up or down movement:

```
boolean lastUp = true;  // default to true since we always assume initially CLOSED
```

The remaining changes are in th 'P' and 'O' case using `lastUp`:

```
else if (movingUp)
{
  movingUp = false;
  lastUp = true;              // ADDED
  result.append (count);
}
```

...

```
else if (movingDown)
{
  movingDown = false;
  lastUp = false;            // ADDED
  result.append (count);
}
```

... and update default case

```
else 
{
    movingUp = lastUp;         // CHANGED
    movingDown = !lastUp;      // ADDED
    result.append(movingUp ? ++count : --count); // CHANGED
}
```

And in 'O' case:

```
{
    movingUp = !movingUp;     // CHANGED
    movingDown = !movingDown; // CHANGED
    lastUp = !lastUp;         // ADDED
    result.append(movingUp ? ++count : --count); // CHANGED
}
```

**Long Answer**

Well, the long answer uses a different approach and this is essentially @grodzi 's answer (state then input) which has a great explanation but since it took me so long to enter it the point is moot.

I'll add it since it is in the language of  your choice.:

```
public static class Door
  {
    enum DoorStates { OPEN, CLOSED, MOVINGUP, MOVINGDOWN, PAUSED }

    public static String run (String events)
    {
      int count = 0;
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();
      DoorStates currentState = DoorStates.CLOSED;
      DoorStates lastMovingState = DoorStates.MOVINGUP;

      for (char c:events.toCharArray ())
    {


      switch (currentState)
        {
        case OPEN:
            if (c == 'P') {
              currentState = DoorStates.MOVINGDOWN;
              count--;
            }
            // do nothing for O and .
          break;

        case CLOSED:
            if (c == 'P') {
                currentState = DoorStates.MOVINGUP;
                count = 1;
            }
            // do nothing for O and .
            break;

        case MOVINGUP: // movingup
            if (c == 'P') {
                currentState = DoorStates.PAUSED; // paused
            } else if (c == 'O') {
                currentState = DoorStates.MOVINGDOWN; // movingdown
                count--;
            } else {
                if (count < 5) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 5) {
                    currentState = DoorStates.OPEN; // open
                }
            }
            break;


        case MOVINGDOWN:
            if (c == 'P') {
                currentState = DoorStates.PAUSED; // paused
            } else if (c == 'O') {
                currentState = DoorStates.MOVINGUP; // movingup
                count++;
            } else {
                if (count > 0) {
                    count--;
                }
                if (count == 0) {
                    currentState = DoorStates.CLOSED;
                }
            }
            break;

        case PAUSED:
            if (c == 'P') {
                currentState = lastMovingState;
                count = (currentState == DoorStates.MOVINGUP ? count+1 : count-1);
            }
            // do nothing for O and .
            break;

        } // end switch


        if (currentState == DoorStates.MOVINGUP || 
            currentState == DoorStates.MOVINGDOWN) {
            lastMovingState = currentState;
        }

        result.append (count);
    } // endfor

    return result.toString();
  } // end run

} // door class
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach by using states.

We can list two trivial ones: closed and opened.

I will name them respectively `idleUp`, and `idleDown`.

- transitions for `idleUp`:

  - `P` (user pushed the button): so you are now `activeUp`
- transitions for `activeUp`:

  - `P` (user pushed another time): `idleUp` (keep the direction, but do nothing)
  - `O`: `activeDown`
  - `End` (door is fully opened): `idleDown`
- transitions for `activeDown`:

  - `P`: `idleDown`
  - `O`: `activeUp`
  - `End`: `idleUp`
- transitions for `idleDown`:

  - `P` (user pushed the button): so you are now `activeDown`

Something like graph below.

```
  +----------+   P   +--------+
  | activeUp +<----->+ idleUp |
  +----------+       +--------+
       |    ^    O        ^
       |End +---------+   |End
       v              v   |
  +----------+   P   +------------+
  | idleDown +<----->+ activeDown |
  +----------+       +------------+
```

Notice the (somehow elegant) symmetry between `activeUp-idleUp` and `activeDown-idleDown`.

In your approach you are char first, then state. In below code we are state first, then char.

Instead of considering four states, we only "code" two: active and idle (but under the hood we indeed have four states, simply conditionned via variable instead of classes)

You sure can use a pattern state, but feels a bit tiresome.

```js
function simu (str) {
  let direction = 1 // 1 for up, -1 for down
  let pos = 0 // initially closed
  let active = false
  let out = '' //  the return string
  for (let c of str) {
    if (active) {
      if (c === '.') {
        pos += 1 * direction
        if (pos <= 0 || pos >= 5) {// End
          active = false
          direction *= -1
        }
      }
      else if (c === 'O') {
        direction *= -1
        pos += 1 * direction // instant change of direction
      }
      else if (c === 'P') {
        active = false
      }
    } else { // idle
      if (c === 'P') {
        active = true
        pos += 1 * direction // instant change too
      }
    }
    out += pos
  }
  return out
}
function test(libel, s, exp) {
  const out = simu(s)
  if (out != exp) {
    throw 'failed '+libel+' got '+out+' expect '+exp
  }
  console.log('OK', s, '->', out)
}
test("should stay closed unless button is pressed (no buttonpresses)", "..........", "0000000000")
test("should start opening on buttonpress", "P..", "123")
test("should open completely and stay open", "P....", "12345")
test("should start opening and pause on second buttonpress", "P.P..", "12222")
test("→ should resume closing on third buttonpress", ".....P......P.P..P....", "0000012345554333321000")
test("should reverse while opening", "P.O....", "1210000")
test("→ should reverse while closing", "P.......P.O....", "123455554345555") //thx Andy
test("→ should reverse while opening (and allow pause)", "P..OP..P..", "1232222100")
test("should start opening and reverse when obstacle", "..P...O.....", "001234321000")
```